# 2`s complement in 3.13 format(The range is from -4~3.99) what does it mean?

Tags: c, codec, i2c, twos-complement

I am using a Relatek audio codec ALC5621 for some custom audio processing application.I use i2c bit banging to control communication between the codec and  an soc(cc1110). While figuring out the equalizer part I bumped into a problem, 
which is stated as follows---> A 16 bit register accepting binary input whose format is --->" 2`s complement in 3.13 format(The range is from -4~3.99) " Register size 16 bit (15,0) ,how can I give data into this register for eg:-4,-1 etc?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you be more precise maybe with a more understandable example?

Comment: I need to apply the values like -4,+3.99,-2,+1.99 to a 16 bit register in the codec which is   accepting values in  2`s complement in 3.13 format,how shall I apply ?Am I clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.13 format represented in Binary Fixed-point arithmetic Notation called "Q" number format.
Refer to: [Fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)
3.13 describes a number with 3 integer bit and 13 fractional bits stored as a 16-bit 2's complement integer (quoting Wikipedia).
Converting a value fixed point value given in Q3.13 to "physical" floating point value is done by dividing the integer value by 2^13.
The 16 bits integer can be represented as **short** C variable: **short q;**
The "physical" (i.e voltage) value can be represented as **double** C variable: **double v;**

```
short q; //Q3.13 integer format.
double v; //"physical" value (assuming voltage).
```

Converting q to v:

```
v = (double)q/(double)(1<<13);
```

Converting v to q:

```
q = (short)floor(v*(double)(1<<13) + 0.5); //Add 0.5 for rounding - round(x) = floor(x+0.5)
```

Examples:

```
q = -32768; //Minimum short range
//v = -32768 / 8192 = -4.0

q = 32767; //Maximum short range
//v = 32767 / 8192 = 3.9998779

v = -4.0;
//q = floor(-4.0*8192.0 + 0.5) = -32768

v = -1.0;
//q = floor(-1.0*8192.0 + 0.5) = -8192
```

Comment: That really helped.Thanks @ Rotem ,You are really awesome